# What is Encoding of a String c#

Tags: c#, .net, string, encoding

This is converted from "steal away":

> 6333526c595777675958646865513d3d

Can I determine the encoding of this text?

And if it's possible how can I make a conversion method in C#?

Comment: What is "steal away"?

Comment: he's saying `SomeEncoding("steal away") = "6333526c595777675958646865513d3d"`

Comment: Oh, right. It's base64, then hex. Reverse it by putting it into [here](http://www.string-functions.com/hex-string.aspx) then putting the result of that into [this](http://www.base64decode.org/).

Comment: steal back ,,steal back

Answer (score 4):

It looked like hex, and decoding it from hex as ASCII reveals `c3RlYWwgYXdheQ==`, which looks a *lot* like Base64 (the `==` padding is a giveaway). Decoding that as ASCII reveals the original string "steal away".

Here is a C# snippet to decode it.

```
private static IEnumerable<byte> ParseHex(string input) {
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i += 2) 
        yield return Convert.ToByte(input.Substring(i, 2), 16);
}

public static void Main(string[] args) {
    string input = "6333526c595777675958646865513d3d";
    byte[] bytes = ParseHex(input).ToArray();
    string base64 = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);
    byte[] output = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
    string outputString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(output);
    Console.WriteLine(outputString);
}
```